# How to make a regular expression for combining characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, unicode

I am working in an application in which i have required a regular expression of to detect combining characters.I have made following regex

```
string regex = @"^([~.][a-z])";
```

I have to detect combining characters which are separated from character because they don not exist in the font so i have to check two characters, one is symbol and other is any character i.e ~a.
Problem is that i am not able to paste exact shape of symbols. I am using this link
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character 
When i paste them in regex there shape is changed.

How to make a regex that detect specific combining characters provided in regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Unicode properties:

```
\p{L}\p{M}*+
```

`\p{L}` any kind of letter from any language (but not combined ones!)

`\p{M}`  a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.).

See [regular-expressions.info/unicode for more details (chapter *Unicode Categories*)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)